# Ajax polling to only update data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-polling

I'm needing my users stream to update every 10 seconds to update such things as newly inserted status from other users, the timestamp and the latest amount of added comments.

Now I can use the below, but the problem I face is when I post into the textarea, it takes 10 seconds for the status a user posts to be inserted followed by the same status being added every ten seconds after that..Just under a different id.

All I need the polling to do is select the data that I echo out in the insert.php page and not actually add a new comment every 10 seconds. Is it possible to go about this a different way to just select the response data?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var content = $("#toid").val();
        var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();

    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { toid: content, newmsg: newmsg },
            success: function(response){
                $("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='divider-"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div class='userinfo'><a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('"+response['streamitem_id']+"');\">X</div><a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'>"+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"</a><span class='subtleLink'> said</span><br/><a class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>"+response['streamitem_timestamp']+"</a><hr>"+newmsg+"<div style='height:20px;' class='post_contextoptions'><div id='streamcomment'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\">Write a comment...</a></div><div id='streamlike'><a id='likecontext_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Like</div></a><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div><div id='streamdislike'><a id='dislikecontext_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Dislike</div></a><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div></div><div class='stream_comment_holder' style='display:none;' id='comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div id='comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><table width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><td valign=top align=left><div class='stream_comment_inputarea'><input type='text' name='content' style='width:100%;' class='input_comment' placeholder='Write a comment...'  onkeyup='growcommentinput(this);' autocomplete='off' onkeypress=\"if(event.keyCode==13){addcomment("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.value,'comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"',"+response['id']+",'"+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"');this.value='';}\"><br/></div></div>");
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
    return false
    });
});
</script>




<?php
session_start();
require"include/rawfeeds_load.php";

$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
if(isset($_POST['toid'])){

if($_POST['toid']==""){$_POST['toid']=$_SESSION['id'];}

if(isset($_POST['newmsg'])&isset($_POST['toid'])){
if($_POST['toid']==$_SESSION['id']){
rawfeeds_user_core::create_streamitem("1",$_SESSION['id'],$_POST['newmsg'],"1",$_POST['toid']);
}else{
rawfeeds_user_core::create_streamitem("3",$_SESSION['id'],$_POST['newmsg'],"1",$_POST['toid']);
}
}
}
$json = array();
$check = "SELECT streamitem_id FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_creator='$user1_id' ORDER BY streamitem_id DESC";
$check1 = mysql_query($check);
$resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
$json['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id'];


mysql_free_result($check1);

$check = "SELECT streamitem_timestamp FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_creator='$user1_id' ORDER BY streamitem_timestamp DESC";
$check1 = mysql_query($check);
$resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
$json['streamitem_timestamp'] = Agotime($resultArr['streamitem_timestamp']);
mysql_free_result($check1);



$check = "SELECT username, id, first, middle, last FROM users";
$check1 = mysql_query($check);
$resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
$json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
$json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
$json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
$json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
$json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];

mysql_free_result($check1);

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

HTML/PHP page

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
echo "<strong>Welcome ".$data['fullusersname']." </strong>";
}
else
{
echo "You don't belong here Please log in to your account <br/><a href=\"index.php\">Log in</a>!";
}

?>
</div>
<body>
<div id="responsecontainer"></div>

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){

}else{
?>
<? $user1_id=$_SESSION['id']; ?>

<link href="js/dependencies/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="userinfo"><div id="divider">
<div class="form">
<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id; ?>">
<input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
<div id="button_block">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed">
</form>
</div></div></div></div></body>
<div id="homestatusid"></div>
<?php
//FRIENDSHIPS
$following_string=$_SESSION['id'];
$sql_follows="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1_id=".$_SESSION['id']." AND status=2 OR user2_id=".$_SESSION['id']." AND status=2";
$query_follows=mysql_query($sql_follows) or die("Error finding friendships");
if($query_follows>0){
$friendlist="(".$_SESSION['id'].",";
$t=0;
while($follow=mysql_fetch_array($query_follows))
{
if($follow['user1_id']==$_SESSION['id']){
if($t>0){
$friendlist=$friendlist.",";
}
$friendlist=$friendlist. $follow['user2_id'];
}else{
if($t>0){
$friendlist=$friendlist.",";
}
$friendlist=$friendlist. $follow['user1_id'];
}
$t=$t+1;
}
$friendlist=$friendlist.")";
}
//STREAMDATA
$badcall = "(".$_SESSION['id'].",)";
if($friendlist==$badcall){
$friendlist="(".$_SESSION['id'].")";
}
if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
$sqllimit = $_GET['limit'];
}else{
$sqllimit = 20;
}
$call="SELECT * FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_target= $following_string OR streamitem_creator = $following_string OR streamitem_creator IN $friendlist AND streamitem_target IN $friendlist ORDER BY streamitem_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20";
$chant= mysql_query($call) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($chant);
if($num>0){
while($streamitem_data = mysql_fetch_array($chant)){
echo"<body><div id='divider-".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'><div class='userinfo'>";
if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 1||$streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 3){
echo "";
}else{
echo "";
}
$poster_name = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']);
$target_name = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_target']);
if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$_SESSION['id']){
echo "<div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');\">X</div>";} 
if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 1||$streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 3){
if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==1)){
echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_creator'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";

echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$target_name['username']."'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_target'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";}
if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==3)){
echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_target'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";}
$cont = stripslashes($streamitem_data['streamitem_content']);

if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==1)){
//$cont = htmlentities($cont);
$cont = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a class='user_link' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $cont);
  $cont = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $cont);
        $cont = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tps://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $cont);
        $cont = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
        '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $cont);
       $cont = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})',
        '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $cont);}


if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['id']."'>" . $poster_name['fullusersname']."</a><span class='subtleLink'> said </span>";
}else{
echo "<a href='profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'>" .$poster_name['fullusersname']."</a>
<span class='subtleLink'>wrote on</span>
<a href='profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'>" .$target_name['fullusersname']." 's</a> stream";}
echo "<br/><a href='#' class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>".Agotime($streamitem_data['streamitem_timestamp'])."</a><hr>
<div style='padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;'>";

if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==1){
$cont = nl2br($cont);
echo "<span class='subtleLink'>".$cont."</span>";
}else{

if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
$cont = nl2br($cont);
echo "<div>".$cont."</div>";
}else{
$cont = nl2br($cont);
echo "<div>'".$cont."</div>";
}
}
echo "<div style='height:20px;' class='post_contextoptions'>"; ?>
<?              
//COMMENTS
$sql="SELECT * FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_streamitem = '".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' ORDER BY comment_datetime  ASC";
$query= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$num2= mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num2==0){
echo "<div id='streamcomment'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"> Write a comment...</a></div>";
}else{
echo "<div id='streamcomment'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"> Show Comments (".$num2.")</a></div>";
}
$streamid=$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'];

            $check      =   "SELECT feedback_id FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid='$streamid' AND feedback_rating=1";
            $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
            $check2     =    mysql_num_rows($check1);

$check = rawfeeds_user_core::check_liked($_SESSION['id'],$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'],1);
echo "<div id='streamlike'><a id='likecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
if($check==0){
echo "<div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>Like</div></a>";
}else{
echo "<div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>Liked (".$check2.")</div>";
}
echo"</div></form>";
$streamid=$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'];

            $check      =   "SELECT feedback_id FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid='$streamid' AND feedback_rating=2";
            $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
            $check2     =    mysql_num_rows($check1);

$checkdislikes = rawfeeds_user_core::check_liked($_SESSION['id'],$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'],2);
echo "<div id='streamdislike'><a id='dislikecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
if($checkdislikes==0){
echo "<div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>Dislike</div></a>";
}else{
echo "<div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>Disiked (".$check2.")</div>";
}
echo"</div></form>";
echo"</div></div></body>";
echo "<div class='stream_comment_holder' style='display:none;' id='comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'><div id='comment_list_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>";
$isfirst = 1;
if($num2>0){
while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$poster = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($comment['comment_poster']);
$post = stripslashes($comment['comment_content']);
echo "<div class='stream_comment' id='comment_".$comment['comment_id']."' ";
if($isfirst==1){
echo "style='margin-top:0px;' ";}
echo "><table width=100%><tr>";
echo "<td valign=top width=30px>
<img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$comment['comment_poster'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";                      
echo "<td valign=top align=left><a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster['username']."'>". $poster['fullusersname'] ."</a> <div class='commentholder'>".$post."</div><br/>";
$isfirst=2;
if($comment['comment_poster']==$_SESSION['id']){
echo"<div id='commentactivitycontainer'>";
echo "<a style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"deletecomment('".$comment['comment_id']."','comment_".$comment['comment_id']."');\">Delete</a>";


$streamid=$comment['comment_id'];

            $check      =   "SELECT feedback_id FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid=$streamid AND feedback_rating=3";
            $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
            $check2     =    mysql_num_rows($check1);

$checklikes = rawfeeds_user_core::check_liked($_SESSION['id'],$comment['comment_id'],3);
echo "<a id='likecontext_".$comment['comment_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatuscomment(".$comment['comment_id'].",this.id);\">";
if($checklikes==0){
echo "<div style='width:80px; position:relative;  float:left; left:40px' id='likescommentprint".$comment['comment_id']."'>Like</div></a>";
}else{
echo "<div style='width:80px; position:relative;  float:left; left:40px' id='likescommentprint".$comment['comment_id']."'>Liked (".$check2.")</div>";
}
echo"</form>";

$streamid=$comment['comment_id'];

            $check      =   "SELECT feedback_id FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid=$streamid AND feedback_rating=4";
            $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
            $check2     =    mysql_num_rows($check1);

$checkdislikes = rawfeeds_user_core::check_liked($_SESSION['id'],$comment['comment_id'],4);
echo "<a id='dislikecontext_".$comment['comment_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatuscomment(".$comment['comment_id'].",this.id);\">";
if($checkdislikes==0){
echo "<div style='width:90px; position:relative;top:-0px; float:left; left:200px' id='dislikescommentprint".$comment['comment_id']."'>Dislike</div></a>";
}else{
echo "<div style='width:90px; position:relative; top:-0px; float:left; left:200px ' id='dislikescommentprint".$comment['comment_id']."'>Disliked (".$check2.")</div>";
}
echo"</form>";
}
echo "</div></div></table></div>";}
}
echo "</div><div class='stream_comment_inputarea'><input type='text' name='content' style='width:100%;' class='input_comment' placeholder='Write a comment...'  onclick='growcommentinput(this);' autocomplete='off' onkeypress=\"if(event.keyCode==13){addcomment(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.value,'comment_list_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."',".$_SESSION['id'].",'". $poster_name['fullusersname'] ."');this.value='';}\">";
}else{
// It's just a general update of some form. Comes here:
echo "<img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_creator'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";

$poster_name = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']);
$target_name = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_target']);
$cont = stripslashes($streamitem_data['streamitem_content']);

if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==2)){
$cont = htmlentities($cont);
$cont = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a class='user_link' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $cont);
}
if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'>" . $poster_name['fullusersname']."</a>";
}else{
echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'>" .$poster_name['fullusersname']."</a>
<span class='subtleLink'>wrote on </span>
<a href='/profile.php?username=".$target_name['username']."'>" .$target_name['fullusersname']."'s</a> feed";
}
if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==2){
$cont = nl2br($cont);
echo "<div style='display:inline;' class='subtleLink'> ".$cont." </div>";
}else{
$cont = nl2br($cont);
echo "<span class='subtleLink'>".$cont."</span>";
}
echo "<br/><a href='#' class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>".Agotime($streamitem_data['streamitem_timestamp'])."</a>";
}
//FINISH COMMENTS
echo "</div></div></div></div><iframe name='ifr2' id='ifr2' style='display:none;'></iframe>";
}
echo "</div></div>";
?>  
<div class="stream_show_posts" onClick="global_streamcount=global_streamcount+10;refreshstream();">Show More Posts</div>
<?php                   
}else{
echo "<div class='alert_noposts'>It looks like there are no posts yet. <p> Add some friends, or create a status yourself.</div>";
}
}
?>
```

CREATE STREAMITEM FUNCTION

```
public function create_streamitem($typeid,$creatorid,$content,$ispublic,$targetuser){

            $content =  mysql_real_escape_string($content);
//          $content =  strip_tags($content);

            if(strlen($content)>0){

    $insert = "INSERT INTO streamdata(streamitem_type_id,streamitem_creator,streamitem_target,streamitem_timestamp,streamitem_content,streamitem_public) VALUES ($typeid,$creatorid,$targetuser,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'$content',$ispublic)";
            $add_post = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
            $last_id  = mysql_insert_id(); 
                if(!($creatorid==$targetuser)){
                    $fromuser=$creatorid;
                    $_SESSION['lastpost']==$content;
            }       
            return;
            }else{
            return false;
            }           
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't know what your problem is. Could you maybe also post the code of the html-page not only the php and JavaScript code. I mean the part where homestatusid is defined.

Comment: Its pretty long. But I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `prepend()`, it actually adds the text to the top of the HTML Content. So, it is better to use `.html()` as [Preli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561678/preli) said.

You can just replace the `.prepend()` with `.html()` as shown:

```
$("#homestatusid").html("<div id='divider-"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div class='userinfo'><a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('"+response['streamitem_id']+"');\">X</div><a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'>"+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"</a><span class='subtleLink'> said</span><br/><a class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>"+response['streamitem_timestamp']+"</a><hr>"+newmsg+"<div style='height:20px;' class='post_contextoptions'><div id='streamcomment'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\">Write a comment...</a></div><div id='streamlike'><a id='likecontext_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Like</div></a><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div><div id='streamdislike'><a id='dislikecontext_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Dislike</div></a><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div></div><div class='stream_comment_holder' style='display:none;' id='comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div id='comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><table width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><td valign=top align=left><div class='stream_comment_inputarea'><input type='text' name='content' style='width:100%;' class='input_comment' placeholder='Write a comment...'  onkeyup='growcommentinput(this);' autocomplete='off' onkeypress=\"if(event.keyCode==13){addcomment("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.value,'comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"',"+response['id']+",'"+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"');this.value='';}\"><br/></div></div>");
```

Comment: I really don't understand why its duplicating posts every 10 seconds tho and taking 10 seconds to insert the comment. All I need is the user to add 1 comment and then all the comments in the feed to be updated every ex amount of seconds. The HTML replacement doesn't solve this.

Comment: Oh okay. In that case, see there is a `setInterval()` function which does the duplicating work... Can you post the output of the PHP Code?

Comment: All the code I use is in the original question minus the the select comment function which I'll add also.

Comment: I think Praveen Kumar is right, you need to remove the setInterval. This will execute your function every 10 seconds and is also responsible for waiting 10 seconds before anything happens. Remove it!

Comment: So what can I do to update just my returned response data? How does Twitter and Facebook update there streams?

Comment: The returned response data should be like what you need to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the content you load via ajax to be added, but replace your current content then you shouldn't use prepend.

replace the following code :

```
$("#homestatusid").prepend( ...
```

with this

```
$("#homestatusid").html( ...
```

Comment: To be a little clearer. I post a status through my textarea that goes into my ajax that sends the status and id into insert.php and also grabs the response data. 
I want the polling to only select the data and not insert the status over and over..It seems to be inserting the status every 10 seconds instead of only selecting the data like I need it to.